# Does philosophy, based on Archimedean solids, permit an infinite-face prism projecting a fifth dimension of infinite realities from a third dimension?

Tags: free-will, infinity

To quote the MIT work on the Hypershere: 'Considering that the largest Archimedean solid, the hyper truncated icosahedron, has over 14,000 faces, this object alone could contain within it an entire menagerie of never-seen before mathematical beasties.'

What if each building block of matter was in fact a hyper truncated icosahedron with prisms on each surface that projected their matter within into infinite realities that are contained with a fifth dimension?

The notion of free will is at once identifiable as a priori knowledge, as all infinite possibilities of existence co-exist in alternate realities.

Thus traditional notions of philosophical debate on the nature of free will are redundant as they have only been considered in three dimensional reality.

Has there been any work on the philosophical implications of infinite realities existing side-by-side in terms of free will, ethics and explanation of it through the Trivium?

You might initially think with infinite realities that reality is indetermined and we have free will. However, the essential conundrum of free will is that seeing as only one action can be ever be taken at any one moment and once taken the opportunity for choice is gone, do we ever have more than one option? For instance, in the millisecond in between choosing whether to proceed with one action versus another, the entire situation has changed. The original action choice may not even exist anymore. From this point of view, reality is determined.

But a five dimensional reality, of infinite co-existing realities unbound by time, allows indeterminism and indeed libertarianism.

Comment: I'm sorry Anthony, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi Scott - apologies, I've edited it to rephrase the end question.

Comment: The problem of free will is orthogonal to the number of dimensions, its tension with causality or block universe is the same in three dimensions as in five or infinitely many. String theories introduce spacetimes of 10-11 dimensions, it makes no difference. There is nothing special about Archimedean solids either, there are semiregular polytopes in higher dimensions too. On the other hand,  the "essential conundrum" of multiple choices can be solved by having branching timelines, no extra dimensions needed. One still gets "infinite co-existing realities", as in multiverse.

Comment: You might find the book "The Number of the Beast" interesting.

Comment: If you have a hypothesis which you think better explains physical reality than our current theories, you're more than welcome to write a scientific paper and (try to) submit it to a peer-reviewed journal. As it stands, your question seems to just be idle musings with no clear connection to reality.

Comment: I'm not proposing a new hypothesis, I'm just enquiring as to whether there is research from a philosophical standpoint regarding free will if any of the space-time theories that permit infinite realities hold true, such as E-infinity spacetime (https://www.i-sis.org.uk/Golden_Geometry_of_E_infinity_fractal_spacetime.php#:~:text=E%2Dinfinity%2C%20as%20he%20calls,dimension)%20is%204.236067977...)

Answer (score 2):

Measurements overwhelmingly indicate that fundamental particles propagate as waves and interact as points. Neither waves nor points are Archimedean solids, higher-dimensional Archimedean hypersolids or their cross-sections, or yet-higher-dimensional hologram-like projections thereof.